# Why can't i use partly qualified namespaces during object initialization?

Tags: c#, types, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, namespaces

I suspect this is a question which has been asked many times before but i haven't found one.

I normally use fully qualified namespaces if i don't use that type often in the file or i add `using namaspacename` at the top of the file to be able to write `new ClassName()`.

But what if only a part of the full namespace was  added ? Why can't the compiler find the type and throws an error?

Consider following class in a *nested* namespace:

```
namespace ns_1
{
    namespace ns_1_1
    {
        public class Foo { }
    }
}
```

So if i now want to initialize an instance of this class, it works in following ways:

```
using ns_1.ns_1_1;

public class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
        // works, fully qualified namespace:
        var foo = new ns_1.ns_1_1.Foo();
        // works, because of using ns_1.ns_1_1:
        foo = new Foo();
    }
}
```

But following doesn't work:

```
using ns_1;

public class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
        // doesn't work even if using ns_1 was added
        var no_foo = new ns_1_1.Foo();
    }
}
```

it throws the compiler error:

> The type or namespace name 'ns_1_1' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I assume because `ns_1_1` is treated like a class which contains another class `Foo`  instead of a namespace, is this correct?

I haven't found the language specification, where is this documented? Why is  the compiler not smart enough to check if there's a class ***or*** namespace(-part)?

---

Here's another - less abstract - example of what i mean:

```
using System.Data;

public class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
        using (var con = new SqlClient.SqlConnection("...")) // doesn't work
        {
            //... 
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: now i know why this seems very strange to me. It works without a problem in VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Data

Public Class Program
    Public Sub New()
        Using con = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("...") ' no problem

        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) says:

> Create a using directive to use the types in a namespace without having to specify the namespace. **A using directive does not give you access to any namespaces that are nested in the namespace you specify.**

So the `using` only includes the types (not the namespaces) that are defined in the specified namespace. In order to access types of nested namespace you need to specify it explicitly with a `using` directive as you did in your first example.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to answer what i'm asking. However, why is the C# compiler not smart enough (or don't want)   to include namespaces of outer namespaces added in the `using`? (maybe this is a question for E. Lippert) VB.NET supports it as shown in my answer.

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, maybe.. for example what happens if you have another `SqlClient` namespace that is not nested, and contains another `SqlConnection` class? have you tried this in VB ? how it avoids ambiguity ? is it asking you to specify fully-qualified name ?

Comment: Then VB does use the new class in the other `SqlClient` namespace. It seems to win because it is fully qualified whereas the ambigous type is only partially qualified.

Answer (score 7):

This obvious way unfortunately not working but you can make all this by an alias namespace:

```
using ns_1_1 = ns_1.ns_1_1;

public class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
        var no_foo = new ns_1_1.Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! This is what we are using and works like a great workaround to this namespace organization issue. 
ie. If you had more Customer classes, one in xx.xx.Client namespace, one in xx.xx.Server, one in xx.xx.Backoffice and they are all used in BLCustomer you can easily shorten those fully qualify names and use Client.Customer.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in the standard in [3.8 Namespace and Type Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691136(v=vs.71).aspx), but it's a bit convoluted to follow.

The gist of it that a partial namespace reference is only looked for in the namespace where it occurs, and each layer outwards. `using`-directives are not checked.

In your example, `ns_1_1.Foo` would be found if `Foo` is found anywhere in:

```
Program.Program.ns_1_1.Foo
Program.ns_1_1.Foo
ns_1_1.Foo
```

Comment: Thanks. It's still not clear why i can't use it in C# as opposed to VB.NET. But i think i know the answer Erip Lippert would give: because the feature's estimated benefit is not worth it's implementation cost.

Comment: That kinda sounds like him, I agree :)

Answer (score 2):

Partial namespaces will work only if your current class is part of that partial namespace. Using statements are not considered for accessing types through partial namespace.

For instance this will work because your current namespace is `ns_1`

```
namespace ns_1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public Program()
        {
            var no_foo = new ns_1_1.Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, if you change it to 'namespace ns_1.ns_2_2', the 'new ns_1_1.Foo()' still works.  It seems like it looks in the current namespace first, then in the parent of the current namespace, and so on.