# Why does import need the project name and not just the object?

Tags: vb.net, namespaces

It took me a while to even understand the problem I'm about to describe, so please let me know if the description is confusing...

I have an object called "cProp" that defines a number of sub-classes. To refer to these classes in other files in the project, I have to do something like...

```
Dim cp = New cProp.InflationRow()
```

I understand why this is; since the InflationRow is "inside" the cProp, I need to tell it where to find it. Fine.

But this, of course, gets tedious, so sometimes you want to fix it...

```
Imports cProp
```

Why doesn't that work? Why do I have to...

```
Imports ProjectName.cProp
```

You might wonder why I care, but these files are used in numerous projects with different names. So if I use Imports I have to change the project name in a bunch of places. I am aware that Namespace is likely the solution I want, right?

My confusion stems from the fact that the compiler can figure out just fine which cProp (which is the only one) I'm referring to in the code, so why not in the Imports? I think I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Because that is how the language was designed, the project is actually a namespace :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711891(v=vs.71).aspx Btw, C# is much [less generous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061988/why-cant-i-use-partly-qualified-namespaces-during-object-initialization)

Comment: Sure, but why do I need to put the namespace in Imports, but not in the code itself?

Comment: > `" these files are used in numerous projects with different names."` -- Time to move them to their own assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your project has a root namespace - you can see this in your project properties.  You can delete this in the project properties - this will result in allowing you to simply use the class name from another project.  However, namespaces are a good way to organize your classes.  In VB, the project defaults to having a root namespace, which you don't see in your code files.

Within your project, since it seems to be all within the same root namespace, you don't have to qualify with the root namespace for code within the root namespace.  The "Imports" statements are not within a namespace (only types can be within namespaces) - that's why you have to provide the full qualification there.

Comment: I think the last statement may be the root of my confusion. So if I understand this statement, you're saying that a Friend Class has the default namespace, but the Imports, above it, does not? If so, that strikes me as somewhat counter to the whole idea of Imports, but it does explain it.

Comment: Yes - with a root project-level namespace each type in your project is in that namespace (and perhaps nested in multiple namespaces if you use any 'Namespace' statements).  However, "Imports" does not occur within a type - they need to be fully qualified since these statements are not within any namespace.