# The type or namespace name 'Text' could not be found when using System directive is active in C#

Tags: c#

I'm working in VS 2019. I have a using directive `using System;` at the top of my file. `Console.WriteLine()` returns no warnings or errors however, it won't compile `Text.StringBuilder…` without explicitly declaring the `System` namespace, is this a known bug or am I understanding the using directive incorrectly?

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Text.StringBuilder builder = new Text.StringBuilder();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't partially qualify a namespace. It has to be either the fully qualified name `System.Text.StringBuilder` or just `StringBuilder`. Try adding `using System.Text;` at the top of the file instead and just using the class name.

Comment: @RossGurbutt Is it because `Text` is not a static type? So `using System;` on brings in the static context?

Comment: [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netcore-3.1) is member of `System.Text` namespace, not the `System`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't i use partly qualified namespaces during object initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061988/why-cant-i-use-partly-qualified-namespaces-during-object-initialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is part of the `System.Text` namespace. In your code you have not specified the System.Text namespace. You need to either have a `using System.Text;` or use `System.Text.StringBuilder` in the code. I would prefer to have the `using System.Text;` like

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
}
```